# How to get Apple In-App Purchase Icon Programatically or otherwise?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Does apply provide In-App Purchase icon? I've been trying to find but couldn't get it anywhere. In my app I want to show customers various payment options such as PayPal, Apple Pay, In-App Purchase etc. Can't find any icon for In-App Purchase. I've seen some apps using an icon which is like Apple Pay icon but InApp written on it, not sure where to get it?

Is there a way to get it programatically? If yes how?

Attaching a screenshot of an app which has used this in-app purchase icon. Where to get it from?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Apple does not provide an ready-made Button for us.

### Interface

---

You can use `Apple` icon and `InApp` text to make a UIButton, set
layer `cornerRadius` 、`borderWidth` and `borderColor` for it.

use `imageEdgeInsets`、 `titleEdgeInsets` and `contentEdgeInsets` are  to adjust offset.

**SF Symbols** help a lot, you can find the Apple icon with String `applelogo` and then complement it.

```
let appleIcon = UIImage(systemName: "applelogo")
```

It is available for iOS14.0+.

### Apple Purchase

---

Call `Apple Purchase` API manually

You can find GitHub here [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) or use Apple API **StoreKit**

Comment: Thanks for explanation and tips.